# RecyclerView custom LayoutManager remove unwanted views

Tags: android-recyclerview

I have a custom `LayoutManager` (inherited from `LinearLayoutManager`) that needs to calculate the item width of each child and remove all children from `RecyclerView` that has no space for them to appear.

Sample code (edited V2):

```
override fun onLayoutChildren(recycler: RecyclerView.Recycler, state: RecyclerView.State) {
    super.onLayoutChildren(recycler, state)
    // skip if orientation is vertical, for now we only horizontal custom menu
    if (orientation == RecyclerView.VERTICAL) return
    // skip if adapter has no items
    if (itemCount == 0) return

    var totalItemWidth = 0
    var totalItemsCanFit = 0

    // calculate menu item width and figure out how many items can fit in the screen
    for (i in 0 until childCount) {

        getChildAt(i)?.let { childView ->
            totalItemWidth += getDecoratedMeasuredWidth(childView)
        }

        if (screenWidth > totalItemWidth) {
            totalItemsCanFit++
        }
    }

    // if all items can fit, do nothing and show the whole menu
    if (childCount > totalItemsCanFit) {

        // remove child views that have no space on screen
        for (i in childCount - 1 downTo totalItemsCanFit) {
            removeAndRecycleViewAt(i, recycler)
        }
    }
}
```

I have 2 questions:

- Is the sample code above the correct way to approach this problem?
- How can I add a 3-dot icon at the end after seeing that not all items could fit?

EDIT:

To clarify, what I am trying to achieve is a popup menu backed by a `RecyclerView`. The menu has no item limit, instead it should calculate each item width and remove all items that have no space. Also, add a 3-dot menu item as a more option at the end.

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you're trying to accomplish? Layout managers don't lay out anything outside their viewbounds in the first place (aside from maybe 1 item and pre-load during scroll), so what you're trying to do seems pointless

Comment: @Pawel I have edited the question to add explanation on what I'm trying to achieve

Answer (score 0):

Regarding your first question:
See if `addDisappearingView(View child)` could help you,
according to the documentation:

> To be called only **during onLayoutChildren**(Recycler, State) to add a
> view to the layout that is **known to be going away**, either because it
> has been removed or because it is actually not in the visible portion
> of the container but is being laid out in order to inform RecyclerView
> in how to animate the item out of view.

As for the second question - you simply need to implement a 'load more' feature to your recyclerView. How you'll implement this is up to your needs/design (if you want a button or auto-scroll...).
There are many tutorials for that, for example: https://androidride.com/android-recyclerview-load-more-on-scroll-example/ .